# Type Narrowing given two generic parameters

Tags: typescript

I am writing a function that takes any generic string parameter "index", and **any** generic parameter "language", where the function validates if the language is valid and member of Supported Language such that it returns templated string as `${index or T}_${one of SupportedLanguages}`.

I was able to ensure that the function behaves as expected, i.e.

```
const res = getIndexWithPrefixByLanguage('haha') // returns type 'haha'
const res2 = getIndexWithPrefixByLanguage('haha', 'ja') // returns type 'haha_ja'
```

The problem is that I can't narrow down second generic parameter U to one of supported languages. (Probably has to do with return type signature)

full code is below:

```
export type SupportedLanguage = 'ko' | 'ja' | 'zh'
export const SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = ['ko', 'ja', 'zh']
interface IndexMap<T extends string> {
  ko: T
  ja: `${T}_ja`
  zh: `${T}_zh`
}

export function getIndexWithPrefixByLanguage<
  T extends string,
  U extends string,
>(index: T, language?: U): IndexMap<T>[U extends SupportedLanguage ? U : 'ko'] {
  if (!validateLanguage(language)) {
    return index
  }
  console.log(language)
  const map: IndexMap<T> = {
    ko: index,
    ja: `${index}_ja`,
    zh: `${index}_zh`,
  }

  // how to narrow down to one of Supported Language type?
  return map[language]

}

export function validateLanguage(
  language?: any,
): language is SupportedLanguage {
  return !!language && SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.includes(language.toLowerCase())
}
```

I get following error:

```
Type 'IndexMap<T>[U & "ko"] | IndexMap<T>[U & "ja"] | IndexMap<T>[U & "zh"]' is not assignable to type 'IndexMap<T>[U extends SupportedLanguage ? U : "ko"]'.
  Type 'IndexMap<T>[U & "ja"]' is not assignable to type 'IndexMap<T>[U extends SupportedLanguage ? U : "ko"]'.
    Type 'U & "ja"' is not assignable to type 'U extends SupportedLanguage ? U : "ko"'.ts(2322)
```

It seems as though there's need to narrow this down to
`U extends SupportedLanguage ? U : "ko"`

Is there any way I can achieve the desired behavior without having to use type assertion?

Comment: You should probably [just use generics](https://tsplay.dev/NBR3zN).

Comment: @caTS the issue with that is that your example can't take generic string as input.

const [, , file, index, versioning, language] = process.argv
const indexWithPrefix = getIndexWithPrefixByLanguage(index, language) 
//Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SupportedLanguage'.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from `SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES`.

First of all, you need to make sure that you are using single source of true. It means that `SupportedLanguage` should be rewritten.

```js
export const SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = ['ko', 'ja', 'zh'] as const
export type SupportedLanguage = typeof SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES[number]
```

I have used `as const` assertion to infer literal type.

`validateLanguage` should be also rewritten. IT is try that it should be a custom typeguard, however, since you are using `Array.prototype.includes`, you need to make extra trick:

```js
const withTuple = <
  List extends string[]
>(list: readonly [...List]) =>
  (prop: string): prop is List[number] =>
    list.includes(prop)

const validateLanguage = withTuple(SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
```

I had to curry this typeguard, but now we don't have any typescript errors and this code is safe (no `any`). Please see my article [TypeScript useful patterns](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns)

As for using consditional type in a place of return type. THis feature is not supported in typescript. In order to make it work you need to overload your function and then you are allowed to use conditional typings.

See full code:

```js
export const SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = ['ko', 'ja', 'zh'] as const
export type SupportedLanguage = typeof SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES[number]

interface IndexMap<T extends string> {
  ko: T
  ja: `${T}_ja`
  zh: `${T}_zh`
}

/**
 * satisfies - new TS keyword introduced in TS 4.9
 */
const indexMap = <Index extends string>(index: Index) => (({
  ko: index,
  ja: `${index}_ja`,
  zh: `${index}_zh`,
}) as const) satisfies IndexMap<Index>

const withTuple = <
  List extends string[]
>(list: readonly [...List]) =>
  (prop: string): prop is List[number] =>
    list.includes(prop)

const validateLanguage = withTuple(SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);

export function getIndexWithPrefixByLanguage<
  T extends string,
  U extends string,
>(index: T, language?: U): IndexMap<T>[U extends SupportedLanguage ? U : 'ko']
export function getIndexWithPrefixByLanguage(index: string, language?: string) {
  if (!language || !validateLanguage(language)) {
    return index
  }

  return indexMap(index)[language]

}

// "hello_ja"
const result = getIndexWithPrefixByLanguage('hello', 'ja')
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAQpvm)